# How to install libxml2-dev in the cluster

Tags: r, cluster-computing

To install the `pmml` package, it needs the `XML` package, and the latter needs a library named `"libxml2-dev"` in the cluster; according to my searches in the web and in several forums, There is no way to install it in the cluster, I want to know if there is a way to install it, otherwise someone who has its source code.

Comment: http://xmlsoft.org/index.html contains links to libxml2 binaries for Windows/macOS/Unix. According to CRAN, there is no need for the dev version actually.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i need the source code to compile it with "make"

Comment: I'd highly advice *against* compiling `libxml2-dev` from source. I assume the "cluster" you are referring to is running some Linux derivative. Best to ask your sysadmin to install `libxml2-dev` on the cluster using the Linux flavour-specific package manager on the cluster.